# Python array index slicing with [[ ]]

Tags: python, numpy

```
centers = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(centers[[0,0,0,0,0,1,1]])
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]
 [4 5 6]]
```

What is this feature? I'm not sure what is this called.

Comment: This is covered in the reference documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: thanks. boolean indexing is all i needed.

Comment: @Stark: sorry, it's not boolean indexing. It's an *index array*.

Comment: @kabanus: yup, and I voted accordingly. It was probably a confusion over syntax, which then leads to the wrong search terms. However, I'd expected the OP to have shared *that* effort in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply indexing the array with a *list*, so `center[...]` is passed `[0,0,0,0,0,1,1]`, there is no 'double' bracket syntax. Indexing with a list is a NumPy feature; from the [*Indexing* chapter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) of the documentation:

> NumPy arrays may be indexed with other arrays (or any other sequence- like object that can be converted to an array, such as lists, with the exception of tuples; see the end of this document for why this is).

You indexed the `centers` with another sequence, a list in this case, so a new array is created with index `0` repeated, followed by the value of index `1`, once.

Note that this is *not slicing* the original array; you are *indexing*, and a new array with copies of the values is produced (altering values in `centers` won't be reflected in the new copy).

Comment: @kabanus: the OP was probably looking for special syntax with double brackets. However, they haven't shared their research, so we can only guess.

Comment: @kabanus: that something shows up on Google when you know the correct terms does not make something off-topic, however.